# What is the purpose of a time variable in a sinus function?

Tags: laplace-transform

The input of a system is a sine wave of frequency $1/2$ radians per second. The teacher has written it this way, but I do not understand what the $t$ is supposed to mean.

$$\begin{align}\text{Input} &= \sin\left(\frac12t\right)\\
\omega&=\frac12\text{radians}/\Bbb s\propto\text{frequency}\end{align}$$

There is also that unidentified symbol that looks like alpha($\alpha$) before the word frequency on the second line. What is this symbol and what does it mean??

Thank you!

Comment: That symbol means "is proportional to". @KyleMiller the OP is not asking about $\omega$ but about the symbol before the word "frequency"

Answer (score 0):

The alpha-looking symbol means "is proportional to", as stated in the comments. You can get it in mathjax using `\propto`, shown here: $\propto$. So if $a\propto b$, then we know that $a=kb$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$ and $k\ne0$.

Comment: Nope.  Why do you think $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?  What about $a = 2.459 b$?  Aren't they proportional too?